# React - create hundreds of component instances based on json data on mount?

Tags: json, reactjs, components

I have a big JSON file (about 700 records).

I want to create 700 ListItem components based on this JSON file and display them in List component.

I think it should look like that, unfortunately somehow my `createList` function doesn't create any `<ListElement>` at all:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem.jsx'

import {FOO} from './data.js';

var countries = [];

class List extends React.Component {
  createList() {
    FOO.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      return <ListItem />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {this.createList()}
        </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

`console.log(element);` works like expected, and I can see all the elements being displayed in the console, but nothing is getting rendered.

On the other hand when I do:

```
createList() {
  return <ListItem />;
}
```

It works, but renders only one List item that is not based on my JSON.

(I will be passing some props from the JSON to my ListItem in the future)

What am I doing wrong? I tried to call this like this too, but with the same effect:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.createList();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try to add return in front of FOO.forEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return component/components from your function.

**Example**

```
  createList() {
    return FOO.map(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      return <ListItem />;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ouch, rookie mistake (BTW any idea why does it work with .map but not with .forEach? console log works in both cases, returning <ListItem> only with map).

Comment: [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined` and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with each element being the result of the callback function

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning your list of components, change `createList` to:

```
createList() {
  return FOO.map(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    return <ListItem />;
  });
}
```

note the `return` in front of `FOO.map`

Comment: this doesn't work I believe since [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`